# Transformation in spark data set

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

i have few database tables in RDBMS, in current logic, all these table are joined and gives some data, basically SQL is stored as part of view.
want to do the similar kind of  transformation in spark by using spark data sets,
Now i have used sqoop to push the data into HDFS, want apply some group by and order by operation.

what could be the best way to join the dataset, like dump the required columns into memory( ike df.registeredTempTable()) and apply joins or can i use dataset joins as data is available in different files in HDFS.
please suggest me good approch.

Regards
Ananth

Comment: Why do you want to keep the same concept of table on Hadoop environment? I would transform the data creating Avro documents instead of "applying joins".

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your response. let us say, i have employee table and department table,using sqoop jobs, i have dump the both the table data into separate folders in HDFS. now want to perform below query     
SELECT department_name AS 'Department Name',COUNT(*) AS 'No of Employees'
FROM departments
INNER JOIN employees
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
GROUP BY departments.department_id,
  department_name
ORDER BY department_name; can you please bit elaborate on avro documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go a little further. I would not go for the option to do joins between dataset.

I would follow the next approach:

1. Sqoop all the tables involved in the process.
2. Use Apache Spark or Apache Crunch for creating Avro documents.
3. Mount a Hive table to the data created on previous Step.

Let's play with the example you mentioned:

**1. Sqoop the data: You already covered this step.**

**2. Creating Avro documents**

Dummy data

```
Departament
id, name
1 Sales
2 Technology

Employers
id, department_id, name
1 1 John
2 1 Bruno
3 2 Alicia
4 2 George
```

The structure of the document will depend on how you are going to use the data, can be 2 options:

## Employer

```
{"name": "John", "department": "Sales"}
{"name": "Bruno", "department": "Sales"}
{"name": "Alicia", "department": "Technology"}
{"name": "George", "department": "Technology"}
```

## Department

```
{"name": "Sales", "Employers": ["John", "Bruno"]}
{"name": "Technology", "Employers": ["Alicia", "George"]}
```

Then the queries are much easier to do.

The benefit of following this approach is that when you have a Relational Database Model with too many tables, your queries get more complex, and also, when the tables are too big in terms of size, joining data at running time is time expensive, that is because you want to trasnform the data during the ETL pipeline instead of doing at running time.

Hope this clarify the approach.